# setting variables using \set in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to set the variable in `psql` console that contains JSON.
I do it like this

```
mydb=# \set cfg '{"base":"some url","remoteIP":"ip"}';
```

Then I am trying to invoke query and pass this variable

```
mydb=# select exec_search(:'cfg','Field');
```

However instead of execution if turns into this

```
mydb'#
```

And when press `enter` or try to add quote I cannot execute the query. I have to quit the terminal.

```
mydb'#
mydb'#
mydb'# '
mydb(#
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't postgres use `insert` to put data in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is the semicolon at the end of the `\set` command.

`psql` commands (commands that start with a backslash) are not terminated by semicolon, but by the end of the line.

So you end up with an extra semicolon in the variable, which will result in invalid JSON.

I cannot reproduce your second problem with the data from your question. You get this prompt if you enter a line with unbalanced single quotes.

To get out of that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: the second problem is related to probably my way to pass the parameters - the regular queries are executed just fine until I pass my config parameter like `:'cfg'`

Comment: I have resolved the second problem - it was due to JSON. I minified it and started to work.